# Delete an entire row from a table, using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to code for a row to be deleted in MySQL.

I am not sure how to do this so have picked some coding up from another website:

Syntax:

```
<?php
$personID=$_GET["q"];
if ($personID<="0"){echo( "<center><h3><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.close(); return false\">NO ID ERROR CLICK THIS TO RETRY CLOSE WINDOW</a></h3></center>"); 
 }
 else
 {
 $con = mysql_connect("mysql.XXX.com","XXX","XXX");

if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
  $myid=$_COOKIE["user"];

@mysql_select_db("u716720408_admin", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");
$result=mysql_query("DELETE * FROM users WHERE personID=$personID")or die(mysql_error());  

$cnt=1;

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

$f1=$row['personID'];
$f2=$row['personFname'];
$f9=$row['llmail'];
$f14=$row['personSname'];
$f19=$row['password']; 

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
 DELETE FROM users WHERE personID=$personID
```

Make sure you read up about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the * in the delete query

try

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE personID=$personID
```

Answer (score 1):

In your result you dont need to metion `*` in **delete query**

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE personID=$personID") or
     die(mysql_error());
```